# SvelteKit application not uploading in Azure Web Static App

Tags: azure, github, azure-web-app-service, sveltekit, azure-static-web-app

I am trying to upload my application in the Azure Static Web App. I tested my SvelteKit application locally, and its working fine.
Firstly, I commited my project in my GitHub account using VS Code.
Then I go to the Azure Portal, and click to add a new Static Web App, thos are my following settings:
[Azure Portal Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnwgB.png)

Then in the GitHub, I saw these errors below:
[GitHub Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4Gik.png)

```
Could not detect any platform in the source directory.
Error: Could not detect the language from repo.


---End of Oryx build logs---
Oryx was unable to determine the build steps. Continuing assuming the assets in this folder are already built. If this is an unexpected behavior please contact support.
Finished building app with Oryx
[WARNING] Api Directory Location: 'api' could not be found. Azure Functions will not be created.
Failed to find a default file in the app artifacts folder (/). Valid default files: index.html,Index.html.
If your application contains purely static content, please verify that the variable 'app_location' in your workflow file points to the root of your application.
If your application requires build steps, please validate that a default file exists in the build output directory.


For further information, please visit the Azure Static Web Apps documentation at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/
If you believe this behavior is unexpected, please raise a GitHub issue at https://github.com/azure/static-web-apps/issues/
Exiting
```

I noticed that it complains about the name fof the html file, however, if I change the name of the HTML file, the application doesn't work.

Not sure what I'm doing wrongly. I have tried change the app location for every possible folder, and still doesn't work.

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

- I have deployed a static web app in azure portal using GitHub repository. By using below steps
- Check once in your GitHub the repository is present or not
- First you have to deploy the code to GitHub repository it will look like below

[image]

- Open azure portal and search for static web app

[image]

- Click on **Create**

[image]

- After that we have to fill **Subscription ID**, **Resource**, **, static web app name**,

[image]

[image]

- After clicking on Create we will find below and select **Create**

[image]

- After successful deployment see in azure portal as below

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying, and after you deploy, were you able to click on the URL provided by Azure, and access your application?

Comment: Yes, I am able to access

Comment: I am not, I'm getting the error mentioned above.

Comment: Once specify GitHub repository structure and recheck the procedure once again

Comment: Your repository pattern in GitHub must be looking like mentioned in the image when you hover on it. [image](https://i.imgur.com/j3Ce98r.png)

Comment: You mean public? Couldn't find the page you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, we need to maintain in repository in public

Comment: I changed to public, still getting the error.

Comment: Once check the structure of repository and configuration settings [image](https://i.imgur.com/1i55dQI.png)

Comment: Yes, I checked that, its all the same. If you wanna try that with my Repository, let me know.

Comment: Yes, please share your repository

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error message and solved it by configuring the `index.html` as fallback page in the Svelte adapter.

If you haven't already, install the adapter with the `npm --install -D @sveltejs/adapter-static`. After that, modify the content of the `svelte.config.js` file:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';

export default {
  kit: {
    adapter: adapter({
      pages: 'build',
      assets: 'build',
      fallback: 'index.html',
      precompress: false,
      strict: true
    })
  }
};
```

Note that the name of fallback name has to be `index.html`, or `Index.html` as the error message points out.

The last step is to create the GitHub workflow YAML file. Initially, the deployment configuration file was generated by Azure. But I did trim it down to its essential sections:

```
# Example file name: .github/workflows/azure-static-web-apps.yml
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Build And Deploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          # Change this with your API token
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          action: 'upload'
          app_location: '/'
          output_location: 'build'
```

Replace the `secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN` token. Navigate to your repository and **Settings** > **Secrets and variables** > **Actions** and select/create the secret for the deployment.

At the end of the build and deploy phase, you will see something similar output:

```
---End of Oryx build logs---
Try to validate location at: '/bin/staticsites/77c46228-7025-4323-b3b0-fd597bb14a04-swa-oryx/app/build'.
Finished building app with Oryx
No Api directory specified. Azure Functions will not be created.
Either no Api directory was specified, or the specified directory was not found. Azure Functions will not be created.
Zipping App Artifacts
Done Zipping App Artifacts
Uploading build artifacts.
Finished Upload. Polling on deployment.
Status: InProgress. Time: 0.1096262(s)
Status: InProgress. Time: 15.2129396(s)
Status: Succeeded. Time: 30.3263421(s)
Deployment Complete :)
Visit your site at: https://brave-coast-063a3a503.4.azurestaticapps.net
Thanks for using Azure Static Web Apps!
Exiting
```

Click on the "Visit your site at" URL to check out the static website. If you are interested, I have created a GitHub repository as an example: https://github.com/SzilvasiPeter/pomodoro-svelte

EDIT:

You may need to pin the node version in the `package.json` file to tell the build and deploy action to use the compatible node version:

```
...
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
...
```